# How can I use Dependency Injection to either Override a method or to set a default method when no dependency is explicitly injected?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, dependency-injection

I'll explain the reason I am trying to do this first.
My Initial Hierarchy:

```
BaseClass
   |
ControlClass
   |     \
CalltoBase  DerivedClass1
              |
            CalltoBase
```

Both call paths hit a particular method of the base class
Depending on where the CalltoBase originates I need to use
a different implementation of that one method. 
This is what I normally would have done:

```
BaseClass____DerivedClass2
   |              |      
ControlClass   ControlClass2
   |    \             |    \
 call DerivedClass1  call  DerivedClass3
          call                 call
```

The problem is that this project is growing and there will be necessity for
even more implementations of that one method in the base class.
Hence my reason for wanting to do something like this, I would 
like to only have to create 1 extra derived class instead of three every time I run into this.

```
BaseClass
  |      \______
ControlClass<t> \_____           
 |    \               \
call DerivedClass1<t>  tClass
       call
```

Note: every line except the call lines are inheritance
I do not have the authority or the time to change the 
system so that they would not be inheritance.

my goal is to do something like this:

```
public class BaseClass{code}
public class tClass : BaseClass {code}
public class ControlClass<t> : t where t : BaseClass {code}
public class DerivedClass1<t> : ControlClass<t> where t : BaseClass {code}
//defaults
public class ControlClass : ControlClass<BaseClass> {empty}
public class DerivedClass1 : ControlClass<BaseClass> {empty}
```

Is something like this possible or should I just accept that I'm screwed and make all of the derivative classes every time?

Edit1*****************************************
After doing some more research I think my real question is:
How can I use Dependency Injection to either Override a method or to set a default method when no dependency is explicitly injected?

Edit2******************************************

This code is all inside of a library that the company created and is used by many projects. It is for UAT's using selenium/specflow.

```
public class BaseClass
{
   public T Control<T>(string controlName, string pageName = null) 
                      where T : class
   {
      By sel = GetSelector(controlName, pageName)
      ...
      return control as T;
   }
   private By GetSelector(string controlName, string pageName = null)
   {
      pageName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageName) ?
                 pageMapping[Browser.GetPage()] : pageName;
      ...
      return selector;
   }
}
public class ControlClass : BaseClass
{
   public NgElement NgControl(string controlName, string pageName)
   {
      By sel = GetSelector(controlName, pageName);
      ...
      return element;
   }
   public By GetSelector(string controlName, string pageName)
   {
      pageName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageName) ? PageName : pageName;
      pageName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageName) ?
                            pageMapping[Browser.GetPage()] : pageName;
      ...
      return selector;
   }
   public string PageName
   {
      get
      {
         ...
         return returnPage.Value;
      }
   }
}
public class DerivedClass1 : ControlClass
{
   //SpecFlow GWT's
   GivenAngularClicks(string controlName)
   {
      WaitForAngular();
      NgControl(crontrolName).Click();
   }
}
```

The parts that change pageName are the parts that need to be modified based on which project is the caller. It doesn't matter which derived class makes the call, what matters is the class that instantiates base class.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why are you injecting *one method*? Can you elaborate on the scenario here, make it more concrete, perhaps an altogether different solution exists?

Comment: It's really hard to follow what you're trying to do.  A minimal code sample showing who is calling what, with excess parameters and the rest of your code stripped out might be a lot easier to follow.  It's unclear why you can't just declare the base method as virtual and override it as appropriate during your hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better in your case make more complicated base class - your hierarchy looks like inhertiance used to provide some helper and secondary functionality. May be better to split it horizontally to services and make aggregates instead of making hard-to-understand mixed generic hierarchy?

May be u use only .ctors in classes to initialize and it can be changed to Factory?

Why you so sure that u must to have split-and-then-merge hierarchy?

Bad design cause bad questions. You can do anything with inheritance and generics, but think better if you have to do this...

Comment: This is a work thing, and these are common parts that are used by many projects so I need to make sure that whatever I change doesn't affect those. Unfortunately that means a structural overhaul is out of the question, stuck with the bad design. The base class actually is a Factory but the part that needs to change is how it decides what to return, not the things that it returns.

Comment: On a side note, was this relatively easy to understand the situation or should I switch up how I'm asking this?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't something like this be possible by using overrides, in which you call different methods on the base class? Something like:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void FunctionA() { ... }
    public void FunctionAVariant1() { ... }
    public void FunctionAVariant2() { ... }
}

public class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass
{
    public override void FunctionA()
    {
        base.FunctionAVariant1();
    }
}

public class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass
{
    public override void FunctionA()
    {
        base.FunctionAVariant2();
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason I don't want to do that is because with the current set up I would need to create 3 derived classes for every change I come across. If I could have been around during the set up I would have set it up to make use of that, but whenever this was set up they didn't forsee this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check to see what type you are in the base class.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public void Call()
    {
        if (this is DerivedClass<int>)
        {
            CallInt();
        }
        else if (this is DerivedClass<string>)
        {
            CallString();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base class");
        }
    }

    public void CallInt()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It's an int");
    }

    public void CallString()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It's a string");
    }
}

public class DerivedClass<T> : BaseClass {

}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var intClass = new DerivedClass<int>();
        var stringClass = new DerivedClass<string>();
        intClass.Call(); // writes 'It's an int'
        stringClass.Call(); // writes 'It's a string'
    }
}
```